# John von Neumann theorem on self adjoint extentions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A:D(A)\subset H \rightarrow H$ be symmetric and closed.

Assume $A$ has a selfadjoint extention $B$. Then the Cayley transform of $A$ has also a unitary extention i.e. the Cayley transform of $B$ which is $C_B:=(B-i)(B+i)^{-1} \in L(H)$.

Furthermore we have that $U:=C_B \upharpoonright_{\mathscr{K}_-} : \mathscr{K}_-\rightarrow \mathscr{K}_+ \in L(\mathscr{K}_-,\mathscr{K}_+)$ is unitary, where $\mathscr{K}_\pm:=\mathrm{ran}(A\pm i)^\perp$.

Hence the deficiency indeces $n_\pm(A):=\mathrm{dim}\left(\mathscr{K}_\pm\right)$ are the same, since $U$ is an isometric isomorphism ($\Leftrightarrow$ unitary).

Assume the converse is true. Thus assume given $A:D(A)\subset H \rightarrow H$ (symmetric and closed) $n_+(A)=n_-(A)$.

> How can we find a unitary extention $U\in L(H)$ of
> $C_A:=(A-i)(A+i)^{-1}$?

That would imply that $A$ has a self adjoint extention.

My attempt so far is:

According to:
[Hilbert spaces have same dimension iff their isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625690/isomorphic-hilbert-spaces-iff-they-have-the-same-dimension)

We can extend $C_A: \mathrm{ran}(A+i)\rightarrow \mathrm{ran}(A-i)$ on the complement space $\mathrm{ran}(A+i)^\perp$
by an other isometry $I:\mathrm{ran}(A+i)^\perp\rightarrow \mathrm{ran}(A-i)^\perp$ and would obtain an isometry on the whole space $U$ be setting $U\varphi=I\varphi$ for $\varphi\in \mathrm{ran}(A+i)^\perp$ and  $U\varphi=C_A\varphi$ if $\varphi\in \mathrm{ran}(A+i)$. Assume this isometry is onto then $U$ is unitary and $I-U$ has dense range since $\mathrm{ran}(I-C_A)=D(A)$ is dense in $H$.
Thus $U$ is the Cayley transform of
$B:=i(I+U)(I-U)^{-1}$ that extends $C_A$. Thus $B$ is a self adjoint extention of $A$.

What I have to settle is if $U$ is indeed onto, because I just assumed it. And I did not checked the proof of the assertion from the link.