# If $T:H\rightarrow H$ is isometric then $T$ is onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Assume $H$ is a normed vector space and $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ for all $x\in H$.

Is $T$ onto?

The motivation for this question is the problem I face here:

[OtherQuestionOnStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770706/john-von-neumann-theorem-on-self-adjoint-extentions)

Comment: Do you mean "isometric"?

Comment: Sorry yes I meant isometric

Comment: @MackeyTopology: Some authors actually define an isometry between two metric spaces to be a *bijective* distance-preserving map. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) for instance, or this [MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286732/nonequivalent-definitions-in-mathematics/298931#298931). I do not know what the most common convention is, but the MathOverflow answer suggests that it varies by field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in general. As a counterexample, we can consider the shift operator $T$ defined on the Hilbert space of square summable real sequences $\ell^2$, given by
$$ 
T(\{x_1,x_2,x_3...\})=\{0,x_1,x_2,x_3...\}.
$$
Clearly $||T(x)||=||x||$, but $\{1,0,0,...\}\in \ell^2$ is not in the range of $T$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: This answer is a bit shifty.